# What does s[i] - '0' mean?

Tags: c, char, c-strings, digits

The following code is from K&R textbook, page number 71:

```
val =10.0*val+s[i] -'0'
```

What does `s[i] -'0'` mean here?

Comment: Where is the declaration of array s? I guess its a char array that contain digits and if so the operation you asked about will return the int value of minus

Comment: It is somewhat similar to atoi function.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31487757/694576

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It converts an `int` in `char` form into an actual `int`.

For example, if `s[i]` is `'9'` then `s[i] - '0'` will produce `9`.

Comment: Perrrrrfect. Answers the question in such concise and therefore most useful format. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

It seems that `s` is a character array or a pointer to the first element of a character array. And element `s[i]` contains a character that represents a digit as for example `'5'` . To convert this character that for example in ASCII has internal code equal to `53` (while internal code of character `'0'` is 48) there is used expression

```
s[i] -'0'
```

that is equivalent to

```
53 - 48
```

and equal to number `5`

According to the C Standard (5.2.1 Character sets)

> 3...In both the source and execution basic character sets, **the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>   one greater than the value of the previous.**

So in ASCII there is a relation

Character Code value

```
    '0' - 48
    '1' - 49
    '2' - 50
    '3' - 51
    '4' - 52
    '5' - 53
    '6' - 54
    '7' - 55
    '8' - 56
    '9' - 57
```

For example in EBCDIC internal codes of characters that represent digits are
`240 - 249` ( 0 - 9 ) or in hexadecimal notation `F0 - F9`.

So it is a standard way to get numeric digit from a character independing on used character set.

Comment: OP's code is portable beyond ASCII i.e. It doesn't matter what the actual value of `'0'` is and it'll work even if `'0'` is not `48`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the code is used to convert a string with decimal digits into the represented number (e.g. "1234" into 1234).

`s[i]` is the current digit, `s[i]-'0'` is the numerical value of the current digit (e.g. '9' becomes 9).

The rest of the C code  is just how positional numerical systems works.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `s[i]` contains values from `0 - 9` then it will convert them to number.

For eg. `s[0]='1';`

so `val=s[0]-'0';`

will reduce to `val=49-48;  //ascii values`

so `val = 1;`