# what is "+ '0' "needed for in this program?

Tags: c

i'm new to coding (started like 5 days ago), and i'm trying to figure out what some code lines do.
I was wondering what is + '0' needed for in this program? I kinda understand the whole process but that '+0' confuses me.

```
#include <unistd.h>

void ft_print(char c)  
{
    write(1,&c,1);
}

void ft_print_comb2(void) 
{
    int a = 0;          
    int b = a + 1;
    while(a<100)  
    {
        while(b < 100) 
        {
            ft_print(a / 10  + '0');  
            ft_print(a % 10   + '0'); 
            ft_print(' ');
            ft_print(b / 10 + '0'); 
            ft_print(b % 10  + '0'); 

            if(a!=98) 
            {
                    ft_print(','); 
                    ft_print('\n'); 
            }
            b++; 
        }
        a++; 
        b= a + 1; 

    }
}
```

program is supposed to display all combinations of numbers from 0 to 99 as double digits.
example: 00 01.. 00 02.. 00 03.. 50 50.. 51 51 .. 97 99.. 98 99

Comment: As a test, what happens if you remove the `+ '0'`?

Comment: `'0'` + <number0..9> gives you the ascii character for that number (0 will gives you `'0'`, 1 will give you `'1'` etc.).

Comment: Does any of these answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422178/why-does-adding-a-0-to-an-int-digit-allow-conversion-to-a-char https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598698/why-does-subtracting-0-in-c-result-in-the-number-that-the-char-is-representing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490145/what-does-si-0-mean

Comment: The C specification say that all digit characters need to be consecutive in encoding. Meaning that `'1' == '0' + 1` and so on for all digits. From this we can reverse the equation to be `'1' - '0' == 1`. Which is a handy way to convert a digit character into its numeric equivalent. Or use the first equation to convert an numeric single-digit value to its encoded character value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so, if i understood correctly, in my code there's ft_print which prints a character, but then in order to translate it into its numeric equivalent i need to add +'0', right?

Comment: @David it just prints bunch of commas :D

Comment: @M1dn4z No the opposite. You have an integer value (the result of e.g. `a / 10`), which you wish to convert to a character. Which is done by adding `'0'`. So if `a / 10` is (for example) `4`, then you have `4 + '0'` which equals `'4'`.

Comment: Also note that this is valid for any encoding, not only ASCII.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh right. Like ft_print has "char c" as parameter, which means that if only do a/10 i would get nothing cause that's a numeric value, but instead i need a character to be printed, and that's why in that specific line of code +'0' is added :D ty so much!